# How to ask / to find out about games on specific topic

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For example, I would like to find a review of games dedicated to money and sales close to real world. It does not have to be a real world stock exchange simulation but I am looking for something beyond *Monopoly* (which I find far too random in this context) and games where market is just a component. The game should be also suitable for a pre-teen child that is drugs and slavery business you had seen in *Elite* many years ago is not an option.

Actually the world of *Entropia Universe* is almost a good match but the game actually aims at increasing your real money spending.

How to ask in this community to get a better idea what I am looking for? Is it about business simulation/tycoon games?

A good board game reference I've find so far is *ThriveTime* but I have not played it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for game suggestions, which are off-topic on Arqade due to their subjective and open-ended nature. Take a look at [our help page detailing which questions are allowed and which are not](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Note that, as with other stacks, I'm sure people could always ask in chat. That's what we recommend users do over on SFF.